# VS code is displaying javascript and typescript help (intellisense) twice for any item

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

VS code is displaying javascript and typescript help (intellisense) twice for any item as shown in this snapshot, what is causing this and to show the help only once?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by my installation for the following extension

> JavaScript and TypeScript IntelliSense
>   sourcegraph.javascript-typescript
>   Preview

This is because vs code by default has another similar built in extension, which is called

> TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features
>   vscode.typescript-language-features
>   Built-in

So to have the help shown once as expected, you should choose one of the two extensions shown above (for the built-in you might only disable but not remove, for the first extension you can uninstall or disable)

I kept checking the extensions of vs code for long time until I found out the reason and wanted to share it in Question & answer to the community, I hope it helps.